# Combobox SelectedValue showing System.Data.DataRowView even Converted to String

Tags: c#

I am getting an error when an item is selected in combobox control and value of associatename  is showing null.

```
private void cmbAssociateName_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox c = (ComboBox)sender;
    object associatename = c.SelectedText;
    DataTable dtAssociateID = objMainModuleBO.GetAssociateIDByName(associatename);
    Utilities.BindDataSource(cmbAssociateID, dtAssociateID, MSTAssociateMasterTO.ASSOCIATEID, null);

}
```

Comment: You should use `SelectedItem` and probably cast it to a `String` if the list of items in the combobox are just strings.

Comment: i tried it but it doesn't work.so please give another solution.

Comment: add the error & the location where exactly you are getting it.

Comment: I'd put a breakpoint on the third line and inspect the properties of `c`. By the way: did you notice I wrote `SelectedItem` instead of `SelectedValue` as you mentioned in the title?

Comment: yes sir i tried it and also use DbValue.ToString() but it does not work..

Comment: Please provide more info as @Nikita suggests. Also, explain better what you expect to happen and what really happens.